# glfwErrorCallback inside the main Game-Class?

Tags: c++, glfw

I would like to declare the glfwErrorCallback and glfwKeyCallback inside of my Game class. Sadly this doesn't seem to work. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
class Game {
public:
    void Init();
private:
    void glfw_ErrorCallback(int, const char*);
};

void Game::Init() {
    // Initialize GLFW
    // [..]

    glfwSetErrorCallback(this->glfw_ErrorCallback);
}

void Game::glfw_ErrorCallback(int error, const char* desc) {

}
```

I am grateful for any kind of input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glfwSetErrorCallback` does not work with a non-static member function.  You'll have to declare `glfw_ErrorCallback` as a static member:

```
static void glfw_ErrorCallback(int, const char*);
```

to be able to pass it to the error callback function.